# Is there any emulator available for Azure Service Bus?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, azure, azure-service-bus

Is there any emulator available for windows 10 for working with Azure Service Bus.

I am trying to test Remote Event receiver locally as I don't have Azure Account.

please suggest if there is any work around for this.

Regards
Rajat Sahani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get Azure for free (for 12 months) with a $200 service credit (for first 30 days) here:  [MS Azure Trial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/search/)

Service Bus is included.

***Please upvote or mark as answer if helpful.***